# Passing file's path instead of file's name in XML DOM getElementsByTagName() Method

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, path, registry

I have written a `JavaScript` code in my `XSLT` file which reads some information and then print in `HTMl` page some outputs. I would like to pass file's path in the following code instead of file's name.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //<![CDATA[
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xhttp);
        }
        //]]>
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "test.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
    function myFunction(xml) {
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Version')[0];
        var y = x.childNodes[0];
        document.getElementById("writeVersion").innerHTML = y.nodeValue;
    }
</script>
```

For example instead of `test.xml` I would like to pass `C:\Program Files (x86)\test\test.xml`. This path is also in my registry and then if I could have access to it then I can find it and pass it via `http.open(...)`.

- Is it possible to pass a path? If so, how can I do it?
- how one would read the same path from registry and pass it via `http.open(...)`?

Thanks!

Comment: In general the argument is a URI, in your case you have a relative URI `test.xml` but of course you can use an absolute one, also a file URI `file:/C:/Program%20Files/test/test.xml`. But usually browsers won't let Javascript in a document loaded over HTTP access the file system and even if you load the HTML document with the script from the file system Javascript is not allowed the file system access at all or only in a restricted way, depending on the browser.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks a lot. I have already used exactly the same path, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Well, check the browser's error console, it probably shows that for security reasons the file system access is not allowed. And then it is not a problem we can solve with a suggestion on a different method argument syntax.

Comment: Exactly was what you mentioned. It says `Access is denied`. Would you please let me know what is your suggestion?

Comment: Well, for security reasons things like direct file system access or even registry access is not allowed to client-side script so unless you want to write a browser extension or a standalone app I don't think you will gain access to such things. If you want to have your script in the browser access a file then you would need to use an `input type="file"` element in HTML and the user first needs to select a file.